# Singularities of $ \dfrac{1}{z^{1/2}} $?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to find the branch points of complex functions and this particular function crossed my mind. What I am not sure about is the singularities of this function. While I can see that zero is a singularity but I cannot understand how infinity is also a singularity for this while my instructor says that infinity is also a singularity. Even if I substiute $$

Comment: Your function is not even single-valued in a neighborhood of infinity.  So infinity is certainly not a regular point.  Perhaps I would say it is a "branch point" and not even call it a "singularity".  Same with the point $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z) = z^{-1/2}$.  To check the behaviour at infinity, we observe that $f(1/z) = z^{1/2}$, which has a branch point at $0$, so $f(z)$ has a branch point at $\infty$.